# Bootstrap typeahead is not working with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textbox to specify the Nationality. I'm using Bootstrap typeahead for that.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nationality" placeholder="Enter Country" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="5" autocomplete="off" data-source='["Afghanistan","Australia","Bangladesh",
"Brazil","Britan","Canada","China","Denmark","Egypt","France",
"Germany","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq",
"Isrel","Italy","Japan","Nepal","Pakistan","Sri Lanka",
"United States","New Zealand","South Africa","Russia","South Korea","Sapin","Chilie","Sweeden"]'>
```

I'm posting ng-model data to the controller like any other textbox data. Pop up is coming to select the country but country name is not binding with ng-model. Characters which I type form the keyboard is binding.

For example-
If I type In, I can select India but only In is binding with ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nationality" placeholder="Enter Country" id="country" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="5" autocomplete="off">
```

and Js part

```
<script>

    var data = ["Afghanistan","Australia","Bangladesh",
    "Brazil","Britan","Canada","China","Denmark","Egypt","France",
    "Germany","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq",
    "Isrel","Italy","Japan","Nepal","Pakistan","Sri Lanka",
    "United States","New Zealand","South Africa","Russia","South Korea","Sapin","Chilie","Sweeden"];   
    $('#country').typeahead({source: data}) 

</script>
```

typeahead working [example](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/typehead.php).

Comment: Problem is same with this approach. ng-model is binding characters which I enter from the keyboard and it is not taking  the selected country from pop-up :(

Comment: did you include the typehead library??

Comment: If I include typeahed js file, typeahed (pop-up) feature will disappear. Strange but true.